# How do I echo out multiple overridden methods of an extended class?

Tags: php, class, oop, extend

For this example let's assume I have a file called `base.php` with something like this:

```
class baseClass {
     function testMethod(){
          //some default stuff
     }
}
```

I have another file named 'example1.php' with something like this:

```
class example1 extends baseClass {
     function testMethod(){
          echo 'hello world!';
     }
}
```

I have another file named 'example2.php' with something like this:

```
class example2 extends baseClass {
     function testMethod(){
          echo 'goodbye world!';
     }
}
```

Finally, if I want to output anything that is overriding that method and get something like this:

```
<div>
     <p>hello world!</p>
     <p>goodbye world!</p>
</div>
```

how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Just and FYI: I have a very base understanding of OOP. I'm working on learning more though (as you can see)

Comment: create both class object and call functions

Answer (score 0):

Change your class echo to return and then try this way:

```
$c1 = new example1();
$c2 = new example2();
$text1 = c1->testMethod();
$text2 = c2->testMethod();
echo <<<EOD
  <div>
    <p>{$text1}</p>
    <p>{$text2}</p>
  </div>
EOD;
```

Comment: Assume I'm working with someone else and they extend the `base class` is it possible to display the overridden `testMethod` even if I don't know every extension of the class? Possibly by providing info through a constructor?